# Wait for native ES6 promise to resolve in Rails integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I am writing a Rails integration suite from scratch. The project uses a custom Websocket client (and native ES6 promise objects) for some async behavior.

Is there a way to tell a Rails app that there are still unresolved promises and that it needs to wait before proceeding to the next step of a test **without modifying the Javascript source code**? Most of the stuff out there focuses on waiting on AJAX requests to finish. This is useful for some parts of the app, but the Websocket commands are independent of AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an assertion/expectation for whatever visible change the promise produces when it's resolved (just like you should be doing for AJAX requests).  So if it adds text to the page

```
assert_text('New text that is added') # non-RSpec
expect(page).to have_text('New text that is added') # if using RSpec
```

or if it adds a new element to the page

```
assert_selector(:css, '#id_of_new_element') # non-RSpec
expect(page).to have_css('#id_of_new_element') # RSpec
```

etc.  The Capybara provided assertions/expectations will wait/retry up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time for their conditions to be met, so it will wait for the promise to resolve if you tell it to expect whatever change the promise is going to create in the page.